# Is the power supply Modelo: MPW-3001-ACAAN1 compatible with this graphic card, rx580 8gb 2048sp gddr5 256bit pci express 3.0 × 16 8pin radeon

Tags: graphics-cards, power-supply, compatibility

I only play about 6 hours per week. I am very inclined to buy this generic graphic card so I can play more recent games.

graphic card

[rx 580](https://pt.aliexpress.com/item/1005005207337094.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.main.25.49b9qaZ0qaZ07v&algo_pvid=7d49b047-a7a4-4330-9fcf-863b52ab6730&algo_exp_id=7d49b047-a7a4-4330-9fcf-863b52ab6730-12&pdp_npi=3%40dis%21BRL%21477.82%21391.79%21%21%21%21%21%4021227d8316853211314802631d074f%2112000032167284267%21sea%21BR%214522915167&curPageLogUid=PI0wLrumF1p6)

power supply

https://www.coolermaster.com/br/pt-br/catalog/power-supplies/elite-series/elite-v3-300w/

Are they compatible. As long as wattage is concerned I used cooler master calculator that allows you to enter you pc hardware and it say what whattage you will need at minimum. It says 298w. I know that it's on the edge but I can buy a more powerful power supply if it fails. but I would like to at least try.

Answer (score 0):

That power supply is 300W and the GPU is 185W, leaving you 155W remaining. If you have a 90W CPU you will be fine. If your CPU is pushing 150W, don't do it! You need to keep some overhead for your hard drives and motherboard.

Most of the time, you will not be using your CPU and GPU both at peak power. You just want to make sure your power supply is rated to handle whatever that peak is (including your motherboard and drives).

Comment: I have heard most PSUs work most efficient around 50% usage, although that might have changed with newer models. But his PSU is pretty old so that doesn't count

Comment: I am used to looking at curves like this: https://e2e.ti.com/resized-image/__size/1230x0/__key/communityserver-blogs-components-weblogfiles/00-00-00-09-70/1768.Figure-2_5F00_Overall-PSU-efficiency-curve.PNG
But it appears you are right about most computer power supplies peaking around 50%. Thanks for the correction!

Comment: my GPU is 35W, according to search engines. It's Athon 3000g.

Comment: Make sure you put your drives and motherboard into the wattage calculator you mentioned.